# Cannot alter the server role 'bulkadmin' in side SP

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

i have  application   and  sql server 2012 user ( i need  to  keep him  with  minimum  permission)
i need to perform bulk insert  by my  application .

so i need to  grant  and  deny the bulk permission by using  SP 
when  i try

```
Alter PROCEDURE grantRole   @Grant bit 
With Execute  As Owner AS
if(@Grant=1)
 ALTER SERVER ROLE [bulkadmin] ADD MEMBER [myUser]
else
 ALTER SERVER ROLE [bulkadmin] DROP MEMBER [myUser]

GO
```

i get the error

```
Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot alter the server role 'bulkadmin', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
```

**note that** :the SP 'grantRole' exec from my application by the connection of the user -which is the user need to grant/deny the role- with execute permission 
but as developer i have the permission

how can i solved  or is their another way

Comment: Do you have permissions to alter the role?

Comment: the  SP  exec from  my  application   by the connection of  the user -which is the user need to  grant/deny the role-  but as develober i have the permission

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/server-level-roles?view=sql-server-2017